# d3.nest() sum for object array data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data in the format of

```
data={
  "Month": "Jan",
  "typeA": [
     {
        "A": 24000,
        "B": 24000,
        "C": 24000
     }],
  "typeB": [
     {
        "A": 20000,
        "B": 14000,
        "C": 10000
     }],
  "typeC": [
     {
        "A": 34000,
        "B": 44000,
        "C": 54000
     }]
     },
      {
  "Month": "Feb",
  "typeA": [
     {
        "A": 84000,
        "B": 64000,
        "C": 14000
     }],
  "typeB": [
     {
        "A": 20000,
        "B": 34000,
        "C": 10000
     }],
  "typeC": [
     {
        "A": 30000,
        "B": 40000,
        "C": 50000
     }]
    }
    ]
```

I want to calculate sum of each type( ie typeA, TypeB) for indivisual months,
Ie I want data in the format below,

```
Month: jan
typeA:72000
typeB:44000
typeC:13200

Month:feb
typeA:162000
typeB:64000
typeC:120000
```

I am using d3.nest() to achieve this,

This is my code,

```
    var months= d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) { return (d.Month) })
    .key(function (d) { return (d.typeA) })
    .key(function (d) { return (d.typeB) })
    .key(function (d) { return (d.typeC) })
      .rollup(function (leaves) {
          return d3.sum(leaves, function (d) { return d3.sum(sum,d3.values(d.A,d.B,d.C,d.D)) });
      })
      .entries(data);
```

I am not able to get the sum of the elements here. I'm getting zero as sum. Can anybody suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your data is not quite right, I assume there should be an opening square bracket like this: `data= [ {`?

Comment: this is example data.. actual data is coming from service in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately my other answer was for a different question but I'll leave it in case it's useful.

The answer by @Gabriel is very cool but is using d3 functions but its not generic and the categories are hard-coded in which is not ideal.

Here is a way to do it in (mostly) plain JS that is completely generic.  The only assumption is that the first member of each array element is the heading being grouped and the other members are the ones to be rolled up.  Anyway, as well as generic, this way is quite short.

I also included a version of the @Gabriel answer to show it's easy to generalise also.

```js
  var data = [{
        "Month": "Jan",
        "typeA": [
          {
            "A": 24000,
            "B": 24000,
            "C": 24000
          }],
        "typeB": [
          {
            "A": 20000,
            "B": 14000,
            "C": 10000
          }],
        "typeC": [
          {
            "A": 34000,
            "B": 44000,
            "C": 54000
          }]
      },
      {
        "Month": "Feb",
        "typeA": [
          {
            "A": 84000,
            "B": 64000,
            "C": 14000
          }],
        "typeB": [
          {
            "A": 20000,
            "B": 34000,
            "C": 10000
          }],
        "typeC": [
          {
            "A": 30000,
            "B": 40000,
            "C": 50000
          }]
      }],
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Method one: without rollup
// assume that the first member of each object in the array is a heading
//  e.g. Month
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  headings = data.reduce(function(headings, d) {
      var h = d3.keys(d)[0];  //get the heading
      return (headings [d[h]] = d3.keys(d).filter(function(p, i){return i}) //filter out the heading
        .reduce(function(s, p){   //sum each of the other members
          //p is the category being summed
          return (s[p] = d3.sum(d3.values(d[p][0])), s);
        }, {}), headings);
    }, {});

  d3.select("#output").text(JSON.stringify(headings));
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Method two: @Gabriel solution generalised
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var months = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return (d.Month) })
    .rollup(function (v) {
      return d3.keys(v[0]).filter(function(p, i){return i}) //filter out the heading
        .reduce(function(s, p){   //sum each of the other members
          //p is the category being summed
          return (s[p] = d3.sum(d3.values(v[0][p][0])), s);
        }, {});
    })
    .map(data);

  d3.select("#output2").text(JSON.stringify(months));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div></br>
<div id="output2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not much familiar with `d3.nest`. But I think you can get your results by using JavaScript Array map function. Try this code.

```js
var data=[{
  "Month": "Jan",
  "typeA": [
     {
        "A": 24000,
        "B": 24000,
        "C": 24000
     }],
  "typeB": [
     {
        "A": 20000,
        "B": 14000,
        "C": 10000
     }],
  "typeC": [
     {
        "A": 34000,
        "B": 44000,
        "C": 54000
     }]
     },
      {
  "Month": "Feb",
  "typeA": [
     {
        "A": 84000,
        "B": 64000,
        "C": 14000
     }],
  "typeB": [
     {
        "A": 20000,
        "B": 34000,
        "C": 10000
     }],
  "typeC": [
     {
        "A": 30000,
        "B": 40000,
        "C": 50000
     }]
    }
  ];

var results = data.map(function(d){ 
  return { 
    Month: d.Month ,
    typeA: d3.sum(d3.values(d.typeA[0])),
    typeB: d3.sum(d3.values(d.typeB[0])),
    typeC: d3.sum(d3.values(d.typeC[0])) 
  } 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with nesting like this...

```js
  data = [{
    "Month": "Jan",
    "typeA": [
      {
        "A": 24000,
        "B": 24000,
        "C": 24000
      }],
    "typeB": [
      {
        "A": 20000,
        "B": 14000,
        "C": 10000
      }],
    "typeC": [
      {
        "A": 34000,
        "B": 44000,
        "C": 54000
      }]
  },
  {
    "Month": "Feb",
    "typeA": [
      {
        "A": 84000,
        "B": 64000,
        "C": 14000
      }],
    "typeB": [
      {
        "A": 20000,
        "B": 34000,
        "C": 10000
      }],
    "typeC": [
      {
        "A": 30000,
        "B": 40000,
        "C": 50000
      }]
  }],
    months = d3.nest()

  var months = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.Month})
    .rollup(function(leaves){
      //leaves is an array so use d3.sum
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
        //d can be an object who's value can be an array
        //use d3.sum
        return d3.sum(d3.values(d), function(e){
          //
          return d3.sum(e, function(f) {
            return d3.sum(d3.values(f))
          });
        })
      } )
    })
    .entries(data);
  d3.select("#output").text(JSON.stringify(months));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your code like this:

1. Add `];` end of `data`

   ```
   data = [
       {
           "Month": "Jan",
           "typeA": [
               {
                   "A": 24000,
                   "B": 24000,
                   "C": 24000
               }
           ],
           "typeB": [
               {
                   "A": 20000,
                   "B": 14000,
                   "C": 10000
               }
           ],
           "typeC": [
               {
                   "A": 34000,
                   "B": 44000,
                   "C": 54000
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "Month": "Feb",
           "typeA": [
               {
                   "A": 84000,
                   "B": 64000,
                   "C": 14000
               }
           ],
           "typeB": [
               {
                   "A": 20000,
                   "B": 34000,
                   "C": 10000
               }
           ],
           "typeC": [
               {
                   "A": 30000,
                   "B": 40000,
                   "C": 50000
               }
           ]
       }
   ];
   ```
2. Change your code to:

   ```
   var months = d3.nest()
       .key(function(d) { return (d.Month) })
       .rollup(function (v) {
         return {

               typeA: d3.sum(d3.values(v[0].typeA[0])),
               typeB: d3.sum(d3.values(v[0].typeB[0])),
               typeC: d3.sum(d3.values(v[0].typeC[0]))

       } })
       .map(data);

   console.log(JSON.stringify(months));
   ```

   **Edit:**
   You can use this type of `d3.sum()` function too, But remember the value's that return are `string` '**the part that you missed in your code**'  to see the actual result need to parse data.

   ```
       var months = d3.nest()
       .key(function(d) { return (d.Month) })
       .rollup(function(v) {
           return {
               typeA: d3.sum(v, function(d) {
                   var type = d3.values(d.typeA[0]);
                   var array = type.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10) });
                   return d3.sum(array);
               }),
               typeB: d3.sum(v, function (d) {
                   var type = d3.values(d.typeB[0]);
                   var array = type.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10) });
                   return d3.sum(array);
               }),
               typeC: d3.sum(v, function (d) {
                   var type = d3.values(d.typeC[0]);
                   var array = type.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10) });
                   return d3.sum(array);
               })

           }
       })
       .entries(data);

   console.log(JSON.stringify(months));
   ```